# Get data from woocommerce client object

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to work with the WooCommerce REST API. So far I have installed the official package and created an `index.php` file with this code in it:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;

$woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://me.commerce.loc/', // Your store URL
    'ck_9dadcf73d58fec8b0860bced4b0997d7b3b0f93e', // Your consumer key
    'cs_e63d694c035444c45355339171c682052b2707eb', // Your consumer secret
    [
        'wp_api' => true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
        'version' => 'wc/v3' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
    ]
);

print "<pre>";

print_r($woocommerce);
die();
```

Printing out `$woocommerce` gives me this object:

```
Automattic\WooCommerce\Client Object
(
    [http] => Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient Object
        (
            [ch:protected] => 
            [url:protected] => http://me.commerce.loc/wp-json/wc/v3/
            [consumerKey:protected] => ck_9dadcf73d58fec8b0860bced4b0997d7b3b0f93e
            [consumerSecret:protected] => cs_e63d694c035444c45355339171c682052b2707eb
            [options:protected] => Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Options Object
                (
                    [options:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Options:private] => Array
                        (
                            [wp_api] => 1
                            [version] => wc/v3
                        )

                )

            [request:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient:private] => 
            [response:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient:private] => 
            [responseHeaders:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient:private] => 
        )

)
```

Is it possible to get wooCommerce data through this object? If no then how can I do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: what you require to get as data from woocommerce rest api.  please follow this doc to work with woocommerce rest api. https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/

Comment: I am trying to get the products and orders. I try `$woocommerce->get('products')` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not require to add above code or create `index.php`

just use this end point to get all orders list : `https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders`

To get all Products : `https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products`

This way you can get list of order and products.

To use rest api and do all operations in woocommerce using rest api please refer this link : `https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/`

There are two woocommerce rest api `versions` which are `V2` and `V3` you can use any from this.